# Dynamic query in configuration table - must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, sql-server-2014, dynamicquery

I have the following code:

```
/* Log Table */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LogETL') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #LogETL

CREATE TABLE #LogETL (
LogETL INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
StartTime DATETIME,
EndTime DATETIME,
JobName VARCHAR(100),
StepName VARCHAR(100),
RowsInserted INT,
RowsUpdated INT,
RowsDeleted INT
)

/* Config Table */

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LogConfigQuery') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #LogConfigQuery

CREATE TABLE #LogConfigQuery (
QueryType NVARCHAR(200), 
Query NVARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #LogConfigQuery
VALUES ('INSERT',
'INSERT INTO #LogETL
        ( StartTime ,
          EndTime ,
          JobName ,
          StepName ,
          RowsInserted ,
          RowsUpdated ,
          RowsDeleted
        )
VALUES  ( @StartTime ,
          @EndTime ,
          @JobName ,
          @StepName ,
          @RowCount ,
          0 ,
          0 
        )'
)

---------------------------------

/* Declare Log Variables */

DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
DECLARE @JobName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @StepName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @RowCount INT

/* Declare Query */

-- insert
DECLARE @logInsert NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @logInsert = (SELECT Query FROM #LogConfigQuery WHERE QueryType = 'INSERT')
SELECT @logInsert

/* Clean Data */

SET @StartTime = (SELECT GETDATE())
SET @JobName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
SET @StepName = 'Clean Data'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#hey') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #hey
SELECT *
INTO #hey
FROM (
SELECT 'omg' omg
UNION ALL
SELECT 'omg' omg
) X

SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @EndTime = (SELECT GETDATE())

/* Log Clean Data */

EXEC sp_executesql @logInsert
```

The purpose of the whole query above is to have one configuration table that contains query for insert logging. I want to take this query from configuration table and set it to variable @logInsert in stored procedure. Then I want to do some data cleaning in stored procedure and exec the query stored in variable (@logInsert). But it does not work this way as the error  is thrown:

> "Must declare the scalar variable .."

How should I modify the code so I can run dynamic query from the configuration table? I need to have this query in configuration table as I will call it in other several stored procedures, therefore I do not want to hard code it in each stored procedure as the query may change and I want to change it in one place after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass variables to dynamic sql:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373490)**

```
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql 
   @logInsert,
   N'@StartTime DATETIME,
     @EndTime DATETIME,
     @JobName VARCHAR(200),
     @StepName VARCHAR(100),
     @RowCount INT',
   @StartTime ,
   @EndTime ,
   @JobName ,
   @StepName ,
   @RowCount ;
```

Explanation:

When you use Dynamic-SQL the new context is created. Your variables are in another scope and they are not accessible. You need to pass them, so you can use them.

More info in **[`sp_executesql documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)**.

Comment: Great, pretty easy. If you could also post some article related to passing the variables at beginner level, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @DNac I suggest official doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx there is everything you need to know + sample code